# Replacing Manjaro with Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows-10

I currently have a dual-boot desktop with Windows 10 and Manjaro.  I want to replace Manjaro with Ubuntu.  Is it just as simple as booting up with the live disc (or USB in my case) and overwriting the existing Manjaro mount points with Ubuntu during installation?  Or are there other things I should take into consideration?

Secure boot has already been disabled (I disabled it when I installed Manjaro), but I'm unsure if I need to do anything else before taking the plunge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is like installing Ubuntu on manjaro mount points just a step extra you need to remove the efi part of manjaro too cause that part will not be overwritten in dual boot

Comment: How would I remove the EFI part of Manjaro?

Comment: /boot/efi/(find it here)

Comment: Found a more detailed explanation here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi