# Replacing Manjaro with Ubuntu - what should I put for boot loader device?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, uefi

This is a continuation of my [original question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883084/replacing-manjaro-with-ubuntu/883105#883105):

I have successfully re-partitioned my drive using gparted, and am now ready to install Ubuntu.  The biggest question is what to put as the device for boot loader installation.

My BIOS is UEFI... I've been in it before to swap between Manjaro loading first or Windows 10.  I currently have an efi partition:

```
/dev/sda4 efi 524MB 33MB
```

Should I point the boot loader there?  Or will Ubuntu 'see' that I have UEFI and simply do the right thing if I point the loader at `/dev/sda`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting my existing efi partition at `/dev/sda4` worked.  I can select the driver order in my BIOS, and Windows 10 recognizes Ubuntu as 'another device' in its blue boot menu.